# How to delete pointer only once?

Tags: c++

```
enum Reaction{single,chain};

class X
{
X* parent_;
X* left_;
X* right_;
Reaction* reaction_;//this pointer points from every obj to the same place, cannot be static
};
```

The Q is: how to design destructor in order to delete reaction_ only once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Three immediate ideas:

1) Must reaction_ be owned by an instance of class X? Can't it be owned by an external entity, so that no X::~X will ever need to delete it?

2) Use boost::shared_ptr

3) Implement your own reference counting using a static int. Remember locking if you're multithreaded.

Answer (score 0):

What is problem with this:

```
~X()
{
   delete reaction_;
}
```

Or, maybe I didn't understand your question completely!

Comment: "//this pointer points from every obj to the same place, cannot be static"

Comment: @Fred Nurk: Means every object of X have the same the instance of `reaction_`?

Comment: No, if every instance shared the same reaction_, that would mean reaction_ is static.  Apparently, every object's reaction_ member has an identical value.  (I don't understand why that's the case either, just like I rarely understand the value in any question from this poster, but apparently that is the case.)

Comment: @Fred: If every object's reaction_ member has an identical value, then I don't understand what is the problem. `reaction_` is a pointer, so all *different* pointers from all objects of X might point to an identical value!

Comment: @Nawaz: And what happens when one X is destroyed, uses delete, and then another X is destroyed and tries to use delete on a pointer with the same value that was just deleted?

Comment: @Fred: the pointer itself is not identical, only the value it points to is identical, right?

Comment: @Nawaz: Apparently, every object's reaction_ member has an identical value.  X a, b; assert(a.reaction_ == b.reaction_);

Comment: @Fred: Oops... that means it's shared amongst all.

Answer (score 0):

Use `boost::shared_ptr<Reaction>` in your objects

Answer (score 0):

Use a `boost::shared_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr` (c++0x). It will count references and call delete when needed only.